# Problem with using Integrate and Plot functions

Tags: probability-or-statistics, signal-processing

I'm pretty new to Mathematica. I'm trying to implement the following 2 lines:

```
f[x_] := Integrate[2 x, {x, 0, R}, Assumptions -> R >= 0]

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

When I run them, I get the following errors:

```
Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {0.0000612857,0,R}.

NIntegrate::itraw: Raw object 0.00006128571428571428` cannot be used as an iterator.

NIntegrate::itraw: Raw object 0.00006128571428571428` cannot be used as an iterator.

Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {0.0612858,0,R}.

NIntegrate::itraw: Raw object 0.06128577551020408` cannot be used as an iterator.

General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::itraw will be suppressed during this calculation.

Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {0.12251,0,R}.

General::stop: Further output of Integrate::ilim will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

What am I doing wrong here? I tried plotting the function x^2 from 0-3 and got that plot, but I can't get it from the Integrate statement, so can you please tell me what's going on with the code?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't specify the value of `R` (naming the upper bound `R` is a bad idea in its own right; avoid capitals for user-defined functionality).

Comment: Thanks Sektor... I'm pretty new to Mathematica so forgive me for these things. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want can be done with much simpler and more efficient code. First, you must understand that the free variable in the `Integrate` expression is `r` not `x`, so `r` should be given as the argument for `f`. Next, for efficiency, you should  only do the symbolic integration once, so you should use `Set` ( `=` ) in place of `SetDelayed` ( `:=` ) in your definition of `f`. When you use `SetDelayed` the integral is evaluated in the plot at every mesh point.

```
 f[r_] = Integrate[2 x, {x, 0, r}];

 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, plotting what you call $f(x)$ and $f(x)=x^2$ from $0$ to $3$ is not the same thing.

In the former case, you have $R^2$ which is a number -the way you have defined it- and the in latter you have a function of x.

You can make $R$ your variable.

I think that this solves your problem

```
f[x_] := Integrate[2 x, {x, 0, R}, Assumptions -> R >= 0]

Plot[f[x], {R, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Konstantios.

Comment: No worries. Cheers!!!